# Empty Select HTML (Dropdown Box) using PHP to fill from a MySQL Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am apologizing ahead, this is my first question here and I am still a student.

No time to waste.

I am making a website where you are given drop down boxes to choose CPU, Motherboard, Memory and the rest of your computer parts and sent via email or printed out or generate a code unique to you and your build, so the build is stored in the code. That all comes later.

My problem is that the computer parts listed in tables in database wont load in the  box (or dropdown box) as  using PHP to generate it from the DB. I've already searched many questions and answers on Stackoverflow but to no avail and I want to kill myself (not really, I am not suicidal at all, it's a figure of speech)

Here is what I got. Then I will explain all the problems that have been popping up.

index.php

```
<?php
    include_once 'func.inc.php';
    connectDB();
    testDB();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>PC Builder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body background="background.jpg">
    <header>
        <h1>PC Builder</h1>
    </header>
    <section>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="titlecolomn">CPU</td>
                <td><?php queryCPU(); ?></td>                    
            </tr>
        </table>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
<?php closeDB(); ?>
```

func.inc.php

```
<?php
include_once 'db.inc.php';
function connectDB(){
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
}
function testDB(){
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Debug: Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Debug: Connection Successful.";
}
function closeDB(){
     mysqli_close();
}
function queryCPU(){    
    $queryCPU = "SELECT * FROM CPU";
    $db = mysqli_query($db, $queryCPU);

    echo '<select name="selectCPU">';
    echo '<option value = "SelectCPU"> Select CPU </option>';
    while ( $db=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
    echo '<option value="{'.$db[ID].'}">'.$db[Name].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
```

db.inc.php

```
<?php    
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "theUsername";
    $password = "thePassword";
    $dbname = "tableName";
?>
```

MySQL DB structure.

WebsiteName_PCBuilder

- CPU (Table)

  - ID (Int, AUTO_INC)
  - Name (Varchar, 30)
  - ClockSpeed (Decimal 10,2)
  - Cores (Int)
  - Price (Decimal 10,2)

Here are the problems.

1. Whatever kind of password or username or database name or localhost name I put `ConnectDB();` always returns

   > Debug: Connection Successful.
2. As such the `<Select> </Select>` is loaded with nothing in it but 
   `'<option value = "SelectCPU"> Select CPU </option>'`.

Also, if you know a better or alternative way of doing this, please do recommend it. I am quite flexible changing the entire thing if it it can work.

Here is the website. http://pcbuilder.tariqsendi.ml/
In above provided code, I snipped out the unimportant parts.
Ignore the Main Domain.

Thank you so much, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you overwriting the same var.
Change

```
while ( $db=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
    echo '<option value="{'.$db[ID].'}">'.$db[Name].'</option>';
}
```

With

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
    echo '<option value="{'.$row['ID'].'}">'.$row['Name'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am still getting `Debug:Connection Successful.` even tho I am using random passwords and usernames, which are wrong.

Comment: Maybe your mysql dabatase is configured to always accept connections on localhost. And does not require login for localhost connections. Could it be the case?

Comment: If that is the caseI don't know if that is possible. But I am using Viewen as my web hosting service. It's a free one. Could that be a thing?

Comment: Well, when I was configuring postgreSql, years ago, there was the option to trust all local connections without requiring authentication. That's why I think it might be the case with your mysql server. But I don't know if you can access to that server's config to check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 while ( $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['ID'].'>'.$row['Name'].'</option>';
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, however I am still getting `Debug:Connection Successful.` even tho I am using a wrong password and username.